# How to measure Neo4j Traversal Framework performance?

Tags: mysql, performance, compare, neo4j, traversal

Recently I have a homework in school to compare MySQL and Neo4j.

I read the book "Graph Databases" and the first chapter of the book "Neo4j in Action", in both books they show the different between MySQL and Neo4j is when you want to query "friends of friends of friends ... of a person".

I followed Mr Joerg Baach here [neo4j performance compared to mysql (how can it be improved?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17822333/neo4j-performance-compared-to-mysql-how-can-it-be-improved) and get the same result. MySQL after adding index was pretty fast, and Cypher was in trouble to get the results in time.

Later I decided to use Traversal Framework. Here is my query:

```java
for (Path p: t.description()
                .depthFirst()
                .relationships(RelTypes.friend, Direction.OUTGOING)
                .evaluator(Evaluators.atDepth(4))
                .uniqueness(Uniqueness.NODE_LEVEL)
                .traverse(graphDb.index()
                        .forNodes("node_auto_index")
                        .get("noscenda_name", "person3200")
                        .getSingle()))
{
      //....
}
```

Now I have to measure how long it takes to return the results. I read from the manual of [Neo4j Traversal API](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/tutorial-traversal-java-api.html#_traverser)

> The Traverser object is the result of invoking traverse() of a TraversalDescription object. It represents a traversal positioned in the graph, and a specification of the format of the result. The actual traversal is performed lazily each time the next()-method of the iterator of the Traverser is invoked.

The actual traversal is performed each time the next() method is invoked. So if I want to measure the time I have to wait for the loop to end. Am I right?

And if I'm right, the perfomance of Traversal API is so bad because it takes about 60s to return the results with Depth 4. Any suggestion to improve the performance?

Comment: Do you have your setup somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

It might be a uniqueness issue, where more relationships than necessary are traversed. You can do:

```
Traverser traverser = t.description()
                .depthFirst()
                .relationships(RelTypes.friend, Direction.OUTGOING)
                .evaluator(Evaluators.atDepth(4))
                .uniqueness(Uniqueness.NODE_LEVEL)
                .traverse(graphDb.index()
                        .forNodes("node_auto_index")
                        .get("noscenda_name", "person3200")
                        .getSingle());
for ( Path p : traverser ) { ... }
traverser.metadata().getNumberOfRelationshipsTraversed() / getNumberOfPathsReturned()
```

to see how that compares to the other queries you executed. Perhaps you could could try Uniqueness.NODE_PATH.

On another note: what is the use case for listing all depth 4 users? That's going to be quite a lot always. If you try a more realistic use case and compare to, how would that stack up?